# Find and Replace in Excel file using VB.NET, based on Excell value

Tags: excel, vb.net, replace, find

I am trying to use vb.net to loop through an Excel spreadsheet to do a find and replace. Additionally I need to do this find and replace based on the value of another cell.

The code I have tried is:

```
    'loop through each row
    For X As Integer = 1 To 1000
        'check if the cell value matches the search string.
        If xlWorkSheet.Cells(X, 9).value = "Removed" And xlWorkSheet.Cells(X, 10).value = "Dispute" Then
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(X, 10).Replace("Dispute", "I have been replaced")
        End If
    Next
```

My issue is that ALL values of "Dispute" in column J (10) in the Excel file are being updated, whereas I would like it to only update "Dispute" to "I have been replaced". if the value of "Removed" is in Column I (9)

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
If xlWorkSheet.Cells(X, 9).Value = "Removed" And xlWorkSheet.Cells(X, 10).Value = "Dispute" Then
    xlWorkSheet.Cells(X, 10).Value = "I have been replaced"
End If
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! Not sure what the difference was but never the less it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help :)